# svelte 3 typescript: Unexpected tokensvelte(parse-error)

Tags: typescript, svelte-3

I'm new to svelte and I would like to try it with typescript by following [the official guideline.](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript) I have generated the project and haven't done any change to my code. But I'm getting an (linting?) error from vscode editor (generated file App.svelte):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- vscode: Version: 1.47.3,
- vscode svelte (official extension): v101.4.0
- node: v12.14.0

`package.json` (partial):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^12.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte-check": "^0.1.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"],
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**If you have previously used the old svelte extension**

This error is likely due to a conflict between the old, unofficial svelte vscode extension and the new, official one.  Since the older extensions has been removed from the marketplace it is no longer visible in your list of extensions, however it can still be there on your hard disk.

Go the the extensions folder located on your PC

- Windows (powershell) `~\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS / Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux if using WSL `~/.vscode-server/extensions/`

And check if you have two svelte extensions installed, if so,

- **Remove** the `jamesbirtles.svelte-vscode-(version)` folder
- **Keep** the `svelte.svelte-vscode-(version)` folder

Then restart VScode

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had indeed 2 svelte extensions (both svelte.svelte.### though). I just removed both of them and re-installed the latest extension from marketplace. But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: did you delete the folders from the actual extensions folder under . vscode?

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to delete the unofficial extension; deleted the jamesbirtles.svelte-vscode-### folder under the .vscode/extensions.

Comment: Alternatively, run this on your terminal and restart vs code `code --uninstall-extension JamesBirtles.svelte-vscode`

Comment: Still getting this error